# Why the config item call return error after Codeigniter update(1.7.2 to 2.0.3)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I updated my application to 2.0.3 from 1.7.2 using CI updation document.
But now am stuck with an error in active record file(application/libraries/Activerecord.php).

In active record i tried to get the config item  using the `$this->config` Object .

My code :- `$this->config->item('item_name');`.

But it return an error.

Error :- Call to a member function item() on null .

During CI update i done the following actions based on the CI document.

Updated CodeIgniter system files.,
Updated Plugins to Helpers.,
Updated Class extensions.,
Updated Parent Constructor calls.,
Moved core extensions to application/core.,
Updating config folder changes.,
index file changed.,

Comment: Are you previously using custom config file on version `1.7.2`?

Comment: @HastaDhana yes i a used custom config file in previous CI. And i included  that custom config file in application/config/Config.php like "require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../../../config/config.php';"  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename this :

```
require dirname( FILE ) . '/../../../config/your_custom_config.php';
```

into this :

```
require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/your_custom_config.php';
```

And make sure you correctly set the custom config path.
Or alternatively, you could use built-in config loader method in your controller :

```
$this->config->load('your_custom_config');
```

Answer (score 1):

in your library Activerecord.php

the proble is ... you cannot use all classes available in codeigniter .. in order to do load config  ...

```
$this->config->item('item_name');.
```

change it to

```
$this->ci =& get_instance();
$this->ci->config->item('item_name');
```